# How can I remove the <> characters from the password link in the new user welcome e-mail in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

The URL to set a password on your new account does not show up in the e-mail sent to new users.

The reason for this is that it is wrapped in the characters <>. The same problem happened in the password reset e-mail, but that was fixed with this solution:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/246377/missing-url-in-password-reset-email

I can't find a similar filter for the new user password set e-mail. Does anyone know how that can be done?

Comment: This appears to happen inside the `wp_new_user_notification` function, and that applies a filter of the same name, see https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1994

Answer (score 0):

Use the follows code snippet for new user email -

```
function wp_new_user_notification_email( $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user ){
    /* translators: %s: user login */
    $message  = sprintf( __( 'Username: %s' ), $user->user_login ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= __( 'To set your password, visit the following address:' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= network_site_url( "wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode( $user->user_login ), 'login' ) . "\r\n\r\n";

    $message .= wp_login_url() . "\r\n";

    $wp_new_user_notification_email['message'] = $message;
}
add_filter( 'wp_new_user_notification_email', 'wp_new_user_notification_email', 99, 2 );
```